# Splitting the arguments in the argv array by delimiter

Tags: c, argv

I am trying to write a program where I have to execute 2 programs by the system call exec() .

The 2 programnames are provided by the argv input like this:
./ forkexec programname parameterlist ; programname parameterlist
So I have to split this up at the colon , to make clear what I mean I will do an example.

./forkexex ls -l -a /tmp \; ls -l -a /bin

So I think I need 2 arrays right ? And do I do this by using strtok ?

Comment: At every iteration, you should keep the current value in a list or vector or array...

Comment: You should look at [getopt](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt)

Comment: @Phantom `getopt` isn't available on all platforms.

Comment: Please show a [MCVE].

Comment: The arguments are already split up by spaces

Comment: @Jabberwocky Well... I forgot about that detail :s Why do Microsoft can not be conform to POSIX....

Comment: @Phantom I've long thought that Windows should become an environment for a unixy system (like Macs are now). I think the WSL is a step in that direction. So maybe one day.

Comment: I think you need to read a bit about how argv works, because this seems like the wrong approach from the beginning. argv is not a string. It's an array of strings. (That's not 100% true, but it's correct enough)

Comment: I edited my question, I forgot that I do not have to split up the argv arguments anyways

Comment: I have rolled back - as the question has been totally rewritten. Please submit another question instead.

Comment: @Ed Heal oh okay sorry

Comment: [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq)

Answer (score 5):

Each parameter is provided as a separate element of `argv`.

```
argc    = 7
argv[0] = "./forkexec"
argv[1] = ";"
argv[2] = "hello"
argv[3] = ";"
argv[4] = "world"
argv[5] = ";"
argv[6] = "hello"
argv[7] = NULL
```

You look for a `;` in the string pointed by `argv[0]`, but it doesn't contain any.

---

Note that your approach makes it impossible to pass `;` as a parameter. Based on an edit you made, it appears that you are trying to pass commands to execute. If you're ok with shell commands, you could expect each argument to be a shell command to execute.

```
./forkexec 'ls /foo' 'ls /bar'
```

Using this approach, you would have `argc-1` commands, and they would be found in `argv[1]`..`argv[argc-1]`. These would be executed as `/bin/sh`, `-c`, `argv[i]`.

Comment: Ah so that means I dont have to split those anymore anyways

Comment: No you don't, but becarful, because if `argc=7`, `argv[7]` whill not be defined, and you will have a segfault

Comment: @Phantom, `argv` has `argc+1` elements, the last one being a `NULL`. You you can iterate from `0` (or `1`) to `argc-1`, or you can iterate from `0` (or `1`) until you hit a `NULL`.

Comment: Ok, I was not aware of that

Comment: I've added to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do the splitting, the system has already done it for you:

Check out this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
}
```

If you run this:

> ./a.out arg1 arg2 arg3

The output will be something like this:

> argv[0] = ./a.out
>   argv[1] = arg1
>   argv[2] = arg2
>   argv[3] = arg3